# Connect to remote mysql from mobile application

Tags: mysql, jquery-mobile, remote-access

I have to connect to my database from android appication. My doubt is how to connect to remote mysql via android application ( jQuery mobile and HTML5 )

Thanks

Comment: Don't! People will be able to see the password/username if they hack into your app. Create  a webservice for that

Comment: Since you're using jQuery why don't you just use $.ajax to communicate with your server? just like you'd do in a webpage.

Comment: @m90 is it possible in jQuery mobile also ?

Comment: Of course. But be aware that this will not enable you to directly connect to the MySQL database, but to call a server side script (PHP, Ruby, whatever), that is able to read and manipulate your database.

Comment: yes .. you mean I need to create a PHP file in my application folder and connect to database using that PHP page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way this is done is by creating an API that will feed JSON, XML or a markup language of your choice to your app using AJAX requests. Connecting to the MySQL server through the app is an absolutely terrible idea for 20 different reasons.